# perl dbi utf8 chinese

Tags: perl, dbi

Here is a my perl program runs under windows 2003 with ActiveState Perl installed, version v5.22.1. The script is used to access an old Sybase Anywhere database ver.6, Database charest=cp850.  My question is how to display Chinese characters properly?  Any hint for solving this?

```
use utf8;
use DBI qw{:utils};
use strict;
use Encode;
use warnings;
use open ':utf8';

my $dbh = DBI->connect('DBI:ODBC:yfpy', 'dba', 'sql', { RaiseError => 1,        odbc_utf8_on => 1 }) 

    or die("\n\nCONNECT ERROR:\n\n$DBI::errstr");

my @rows = ();

my $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT custno, custsname, cname
                    FROM customer WHERE custno = 'ABC02' ORDER BY custno 
                    ");
$sth->execute() or die $DBI::errstr;

open FILE, '>:utf8', 'document.txt';

print FILE $dbh->{odbc_has_unicode};

print FILE "中文\n";

while (my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array()) {
   my ($custno, $name, $cname ) = @row;

print FILE "$custno\n";
print FILE "$cname\n";
print FILE "DBI describes data as: ", data_string_desc($cname), "\n";
}
$sth->finish();

close FILE;
```

Here is the output:

```
1中文
ABC02
ñdªp¦qñl(Áf¼Ù)ª¦¡¡ñ¢Ñq
DBI describes data as: UTF8 on, non-ASCII, 22 characters 38 bytes
```

Here is the trace log:

```
Unicode login6 dbname=yfpy, uid='dba', pwd=xxxxx
SQLDriverConnect 'yfpy', ''dba'', 'xxxx'
SQLDriverConnectW failed:
SQLConnect ''yfpy'', ''dba''
Turning autocommit on
DRIVER_ODBC_VER = 03.51
DRIVER_NAME = DBODBC6.DLL, type=0
DRIVER_VERSION = 06.00.0003
MAX_COLUMN_NAME_LEN = 128
SQL_CATALOG_NAME = 0
SQL_SCHEMA_USAGE = 31
DBD::ODBC is unicode built : YES
SQLMoreResults supported: 1
SQLDescribeParam supported: 1
Setting UTF8_ON to 1
!!DBD::ODBC unsupported attribute passed (RaiseError)
!!DBD::ODBC unsupported attribute passed (PrintError)
setting AutoCommit
!!DBD::ODBC unsupported attribute passed (Username)
!!DBD::ODBC unsupported attribute passed (dbi_connect_closure)
initializing sth query timeout to -1
ignore named placeholders = 0
SQLPrepare SELECT custno, custsname, cname
                    FROM customer WHERE custno = 'ABC02' ORDER BY custno 

Processing non-utf8 sql in unicode mode
SQLPrepare = 0
+dbd_st_execute(cb4df4)
dbd_st_finish(cb4df4)
outparams = 0
SQLExecute/SQLExecDirect(1201ee0)=0
SQLRowCount=0 (rows=-1)
SQLNumResultCols=0 (flds=3)
dbd_describe done_desc=0
dbd_describe SQLNumResultCols=0 (columns=3)
DescribeCol column = 1, name = c, namelen = 6, type = VARCHAR(12),        precision/column size = 8, scale = 0, nullable = 0
 SQL_COLUMN_DISPLAY_SIZE = 8
 SQL_COLUMN_LENGTH = 8
 now using col 1: type = UNICODE VARCHAR (-9), len = 18, display size = 18, prec = 8, scale = 0
DescribeCol column = 2, name = c, namelen = 9, type = VARCHAR(12), precision/column size = 12, scale = 0, nullable = 1
 SQL_COLUMN_DISPLAY_SIZE = 12
 SQL_COLUMN_LENGTH = 12
 now using col 2: type = UNICODE VARCHAR (-9), len = 26, display size = 26, prec = 12, scale = 0
DescribeCol column = 3, name = c, namelen = 5, type = VARCHAR(12), precision/column size = 50, scale = 0, nullable = 1
 SQL_COLUMN_DISPLAY_SIZE = 50
 SQL_COLUMN_LENGTH = 50
 now using col 3: type = UNICODE VARCHAR (-9), len = 102, display size = 102, prec = 50, scale = 0
-dbd_describe done_bind=0
have 3 fields
-dbd_st_execute(cb4df4)=-1
FETCH odbc_has_unicode
bind_columns fbh=d4ba6c fields=3
Bind 1: type = UNICODE CHAR(-8), buf=dc6794, buflen=18
Bind 2: type = UNICODE CHAR(-8), buf=dc67a8, buflen=26
Bind 3: type = UNICODE CHAR(-8), buf=dc67c4, buflen=102
bind_columns=0
SQLFetch=0
fetch num_fields=3
fetch col#1 c datalen=10 displ=18
SQL_C_WCHAR data = 'ABC02'
fetch col#2 c datalen=20 displ=26
SQL_C_WCHAR data = "ñdªp(ñ¦¥P)"
fetch col#3 c datalen=44 displ=102
SQL_C_WCHAR data = "ñdªp¦qñl(Áf¼Ù)ª¦¡¡ñ¢Ñq"
SQLFetch=100
Getting more results: 100
No more results -- outparams = 0
dbd_st_finish(cb4df4)
dbd_st_finish closed query:
SQLFreeHandle(stmt)=0
SQLDisconnect=0
DBD::ODBC Disconnected!
```

B/R
Gene Leung